# Unable to open image file in Android - File not found exception

Tags: android, filenotfoundexception

I have [this](https://market.android.com/details?id=hk.bcsw.epodcast&feature=order_history) app installed in my device (Nexus s).
It caches some images if you use this app. This is why it shows cached images in my device's gallery.

I use cursor to get the path

```
final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
Cursor imagecursor = managedQuery(
        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns,
        MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " = " + id, null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
if (imagecursor != null && imagecursor.getCount() > 0){
    imagecursor.moveToPosition(0);
    String path = imagecursor.getString(imagecursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
    Log.d("path", path);
    File f = new File("file://" + path);
    Log.d("check_file", "" + f.exists());
}
```

I get the path:

> /mnt/sdcard/cache/hk.ignition.podcast/cartoon/2/http%3A%2F%2Fbigcity.learnenglishapps.com%2Fimages%2Fcartoons%2Fset2%2Ffast-food-new-1.png

Downloaded image is:
http://bigcity.learnenglishapps.com/images/cartoons/set2/fast-food-new-1.png

When I pull the file or explore it with file manager like Astro, its there.
But when I check if file exist, then it says `false`.

Is there any character issue?

**Update:**

Removing `file://` worked to check if file exist.

Next is, I'd like to open that file in gallery.

1. should I use this path to open image?
   But that not worked:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(
                Uri.parse("file:///mnt/sdcard/cache/hk.ignition.podcast/cartoon/2/http%3A%2F%2Fbigcity.learnenglishapps.com%2Fimages%2Fcartoons%2Fset2%2Ffast-food-new-1.png"),
                "image/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 3);
```

1. Or I should try to get `content://` style path from MediaStore?

**Update 2:**

Solved using :

```
Uri.fromFile(f);
```

**Instead of `Uri.Parse()`. As it builds `/` character from encode format.**

Comment: I DON'T KNOW MUCH IDEA ABOUT WHAT U DOIN.. BUT DO U THINK CURSOR HOLDS A FILE..? OR DOES IT JUST HOLD DATA..?

Comment: On statement `Log.d("path", path);` I get correct path shown above

Comment: you are right.. but i think you are trying to find a file inside cursor which holds a reference to the image memory in its own way and not the exact path.. thing u r getting is not the exact path..

Comment: What ever path u r getting is just String.valueOf(//image.png).. Not the path..

Comment: Try to change `new File("file://" + path)` to just `new File(path)`

Comment: new File(path) worked, thanks @Daniel_sk, add as answer to get points!

Comment: Agree with Daniel_sk, the `file://` prefix never worked for me. It works however in JavaSE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `new File("file://" + path)` to just `new File(path)`

Comment: Hey But that is not enough for me, sorry for that, will you see my updates on question?

Comment: Try this: 
`intent.setDataAndType(intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),    "image/*");` where the file is your `new File("file://" + path)`.